# Multi-type max-flow

Tags: optimization, network-flow

Suppose you have $m $ sources $s_i$ and $n $ sinks $t_j$, but every source produces a certain type of flow, out of $k $ types, and every sink demands a certain type as well. We would like to know if it is possible to satisfy all demands given the constraints in the network. Assume different flows types all have a certain weight, which is used to compare against edge capacities, and also to check for satisfying the demands.

Is there a formulation of this to a regular max-flow algorithm?

Comment: Perhaps there is. What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is an instance of [multi-commodity network flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-commodity_flow_problem).  If you insist on integer flows, the problem is NP-hard, but if you allow flows to take fractional values, the problem can be solved in polynomial time using linear programming.